String#gsub how to use a match occurrence in the replace attribute and also insert a break line
With String#gsub I can insert break lines in the replace attribute:
"my string".gsub(/\s/, "\n") #=> "my\nstring"

But if I also what to use part of the regex match in the replace attribute I am forced to use single quotas ('). And then I don't know how to also insert a break line.
I have tried:
> "my string".gsub!(/(my )/, '\1\n')
=> "my \\nstring"
> "my string".gsub!(/(my )/, '\1\\n')
=> "my \\nstring"
> "my string".gsub!(/(my )/, '\1\\\n')
=> "my \\nstring"
> "my string".gsub!(/(my )/, '\1\\\\n')
=> "my \\nstring"
> "my string".gsub!(/(my )/, '\1\\\\\n')
=> "my \\\\nstring"
> "my string".gsub!(/(my )/, '\1\\\\\n')
=> "my \\\\nstring"

Nothing works.

While the simplest option is to use 2 backslashes for the back ref "my string".gsub!(/(my )/, "\\1\n"). In your simple example you could use a look behind. "my string".gsub!(/(?<=my )/, "\n"). You can also mix the single an double quotes while using the the backref "my string".gsub!(/(my )/, '\1'.concat("\n"))

You don't need to use single quotes. Just use double quotes and escape \1 to \\1:
irb> "my string".gsub(/(my )/, "\\1\n")
=> "my \nstring"

The difference between single and double quotes is that in single quoted strings, you cannot use escape sequences (other than for single quotes). These strings are equivalent:
irb> '\1' == "\\1"
=> true
irb> '\n' == "\\n"
=> true


This is mentioned in the docs: "A back-reference is typically preceded by an additional backslash. For example, if you want to write a back-reference \& in replacement with a double-quoted string literal, you need to write "..\\&..".". It used to be right in the documentation for String#gsub but has since been moved to the general documentation for Substitution Methods

@engineersmnky but this didn't work "my string".gsub!(/(my )/, '\1\\n') #=> "my \\nstring"

@fguillen the docs stated if you want to write a back-reference...with a double-quoted string literal. You are comparing that statement to a line break in a single-quoted literal.

You can use multiple quotation styles at once. Although rarely used, you can mix and match string literals with different quotation styles in Ruby.
From the docs:

Any combination of adjacent single-quote, double-quote, percent strings will be concatenated as long as a percent-string is not last.

Applied to your problem:
"my string".gsub(/(my )/, '\1' "\n")
#=> "my \nstring"

In the above code '\1' "\n" represents a single string instance. You can also paste these combined literals into IRB and it will return its double-quoted string literal equivalent:
'\1' "\n"
#=> "\\1\n"

Which in turn you can use in your code:
"my string".gsub(/(my )/, "\\1\n")
#=> "my \nstring"


Not my downvote as I like the more esoteric side of ruby. In that vein the space between them is technically unecessary e.g. '\1'"\n" and if you really want to upset some people ?\\+?1+?\n or ?\\<<?1<<?\n (which almost looks like an instructional sequence)

That might be useful for obfuscation :) << however are method calls whereas adjacent literals are handled at the parser stage.

They absolutely are because the parser does not allow for character literal adjacency, it's just all in good fun and understanding of the language. Just like ?????:??.
